# Undefined symbols with Linux kernel driver build (NVidia)

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, nvidia

I am having issues with my kernel driver build. I'm and building a custom (albeit very basic) NVidia RDMA driver and am receiving build warnings during the make file. Specifically it is looking for two NVidia API calls nvidia_p2p_put_pages and nvidia_p2p_get_pages. Using 'nm' is see these entry points are in the NVidia driver module (nvidia.ko). However, I'm not familiar enough with the internals of the Linux driver make file system to locate those entry points at build time.

The RDMA tool kit documentation refers to an extraction script "./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-.run" and a build directory. However, I was unable to locate any build files after extracting the latest driver sources.

As you can tell, I'm rather new to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#kernel-api), these symbols can be found in `nv-p2p.h` header file.  Are you including that header file?  It sounds like you're wondering what libraries to link against, but this clarity of this question might be improved if you provide the *actual error output* you are seeing.  You might also mention which driver version you are using and where you got the installer (.run file) for it.

Comment: Download the nvidia driver runfile installer, such as [319.72](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/319.72/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72.run).  Get command line options with `sh NVIDIA-L... --advanced-options`  Run an extract-only job with `sh NVIDIA-L... -x`  Then change into the created directory.  You'll see a bunch of nvidia libraries.  Then change into the `kernel` directory, and you see the header files like `nv-p2p.h` and others.  You'll also find an overall `makefile` and a `Makefile.nvidia` which shows how to build the kernel module.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for. The warnings appear to be move of a link issue:

WARNING: "nvidia_p2p_put_pages" [/<ProjectDir>/kernel_module/gpudirect_rdma.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "nvidia_p2p_get_pages" [/<ProjectDir>/kernel_module/gpudirect_rdma.ko] undefined!

Your second set of instructions seem to be what I need. I'll give a try shortly. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic GPUDirect RDMA documentation is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html).
As indicated in [section 4.3](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html#kernel-api), building an nvidia driver linux kernel module requires various driver header files and makefiles.

These files can be accessed as follows:

1. get an appropriate NVIDIA linux driver installer (.run file) such as 319.72 [here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/319.72/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72.run)
2. All nvidia linux driver installers have command line switch options.  Basic options can be found by appending `--help` to the driver installer command string, such as:

   ```
   sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72.run --help
   ```

   more advanced options can be accessed with:

   ```
   sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72.run --advanced-options
   ```
3. one of the advanced options is `-x` which will only extract the driver files, it will not "install" any:

   ```
   sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72.run -x
   ```
4. This will create a directory where the files are available.  Within this directory, the `kernel` directory has the necessary header files and a sample kernel module `makefile` which can be used to learn appropriate libraries to link against:

   ```
   cd NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72/kernel
   ```